# Querying for records where all records in an association meet multiple criteria

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have four tables, `albums`, `songs`, `tags`, and `song_tags`, and their relevant models in Rails, and I want to find all albums where every song has the tags with ids 1, 2, and 3. For this example, let's say I'm looking for some workout albums and I want every song in them to be tagged "rock", "energetic" and "instrumental".

Is there a simple way to find this with a small number of queries?

EDIT:

To clarify, `song_tags` is a join table for a many-to-many relationship between `songs` and `tags`, so my associations are as follows:

```
#app/models/albums.rb

has_many :songs

#app/models/songs.rb

has_many :song_tags
has_many :tags, through: :song_tags
belongs_to :album

#app/models/tags.rb

has_many :song_tags
has_many :songs, through: :song_tags

#app/models/song_tag.rb

belongs_to :tag
belongs_to :song
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ActiveRecord way to do it:  `.includes`[API dock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes)

#### Assumed relationships

I've assumed you have the following code:

```
#app/models/albums.rb

has_many :songs

#app/models/songs.rb

has_many :tags
belongs_to :album

#app/models/tags.rb

belongs_to :song
has_one :song_tag

#app/models/song_tag.rb
```

#### Query Interface

Essentially what you would do is chain a call starting with the Album class.

```
Album.includes(songs: {tags: :song_tags}).where('song_tags.name = ?', ['instrumental', 'rock', 'energetic'])
```

Some additional information on this can be found at the [API.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Eager+loading+of+associations)

Comment: Thanks for responding, I updated my question to clarify what associations I have. Also, as far as I can tell, that finds the albums where each song has at least one of the relevant tags, rather than all of them.

Comment: Here's a stab in the dark.   I'm not SQL-fu enough to answer this without setting up a clone:    
    Album.includes(songs: :tags).where('tags.name = ?',['instrumental', 'rock', 'energetic']).group('song.name').having('COUNT(tags.id) == 3')

Comment: It's an improvement, but finds albums where at least one song meets the tags criteria, rather than albums where all songs do. Also changed the includes to a join, put the `?` in the `where` statement in parentheses, and grouped by album ids as well, to fix miscellaneous errors. I could verify that the number of songs before filtering for tag names is the same as afterwards, somehow... Hmm.